# Drupal does not recognize my website has been installed

Tags: linux, drupal, content-management-system, installation

After a successful Drupal install, I was trying to follow the security recommendations and reverted the settings.php file to 444 permissions (read, read, read). Then, all of a sudden, right  after doing that, Drupal does not recognize the installation process was completed. It went back to the install screen. Worst of all. I did chmod back to 666 (write, write, write) but it does not work any more.

When I move forward as if I was going to install Drupal again, he tells me he does not have permissions to create the files folder under sites/default... But since the installation has already been completed... the files folder is already there... I am puzzled... Could it be some sort of server caching? Since this is one of my first adventures with a Linux server, I am a bit confused. Any help appreciated... Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Check your folders permissions there's settings.php...

Comment: Hey, thanks, you are right. I changed the folders permission and that screwed the whole thing. I thought that setting the folder for 666 would solve. But it did not. Folders must be set to 755... Correct?

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem to be that when I changed the settings.php file permissions to 444, I also changed the sites/default folder permissions to 444. After I realized there was a problem, I changed it to 666, but it still wasn't working. The web server could not see anything inside that folder. Then finally I have set it for 755 copying other folder''s permissions... Bingo! works normally.